# how to disable link when its clicked?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i want to disable link when i clicked on a link,here is my code:

```
<a href="?cmd=7" style="color:#00F; margin-left:15px; text-decoration:underline">Past 7 Days</a>
<a href="?cmd=14" style="color:#00F; margin-left:15px; text-decoration:underline">Past 14 Days</a>
<a href="?cmd=30" style="color:#00F; margin-left:15px; text-decoration:underline">Past 30 Days</a>
<a href="?cmd=custom" style="color:#00F; margin-left:15px; text-decoration:underline">Set A Custom Date Range</a>
```

i want when i click past 7 days link this link is disabled or ther links enabled,as soon then if i clicked on past 14 days link,past 7 day link is enabled and past 14 days link is disabled.how i do this?

Comment: Am I the only one around here who thinks you want to achieve the effect across page loads?

Comment: no one answer help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('a').on('click',function(){
   $('a').removeAttr('disabled');
   $(this).attr('disabled',true);
})
```

or

```
.disable
{
 pointer-events: none;
 cursor: default;
}

$('a').on('click',function(){
    $('a').removeClass('disable');
    $(this).addClass('disable');
})
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to achieve the effect across page loads.

Comment: it may be because of your jquery is loaded  before you run your code , or jquery conflict

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14203125/typeerror-is-null-error-in-firebug-but-code-works-on-jsfiddle

Comment: i remove TypeError: $(...) is null but my link not disable i want my link is disabled its color and underline remove

Comment: $(this).css('color','red')  ,you can add or remove what ever you need

Answer (score 1):

CSS:

```
a:visited
{
 pointer-events: none;
 cursor: default;
}
```

Comment: From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited): "The :visited CSS pseudo-class lets you select only links that have been visited." That's not what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

use this code to disable using jquery

```
$("a").on('click',function(){
$(this).attr('disabled',true);
})
```

Comment: 1. `disabled` should not be used for `<a>`. 2. This does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('a').on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since my reputation doesn't let me comment yet, I'll post is as an answer here. This is intended to improove Karthick Kumar Ganesh's answer.

Depending on what jq-version you are using, you should use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) for setting attributes / propperties.

Also I would use a class on your links if you're not just addressing anchors or adding get parameters, that should be disabled so that not all links are disabled after clicking.

```
$("a.disabable").on('click',function(){
  $(this).prop('disabled',true);
})
```

Lastly it makes perfect sense to add a `target="_blank"` or something similar to your links, so that your link opens in a new tab. Otherwise it makes no sense to me to disable a link, after it has been clicked.

An example link would look something like this

```
<a href="wher/you/want/to/go" class="disabable" target="blank" style="[...]">Foo</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the **only** solution so far that works across page loads as the OP described (I assume clicks on the anchors change the document location and therefore reload the page).

HTML (added `class` attributes):

```
<a class="cmd-7" href="?cmd=7" style="color:#00F; margin-left:15px; text-decoration:underline">Past 7 Days</a>
<a class="cmd-14" href="?cmd=14" style="color:#00F; margin-left:15px; text-decoration:underline">Past 14 Days</a>
<a class="cmd-30" href="?cmd=30" style="color:#00F; margin-left:15px; text-decoration:underline">Past 30 Days</a>
<a class="cmd-custom" href="?cmd=custom" style="color:#00F; margin-left:15px; text-decoration:underline">Set A Custom Date Range</a>
```

JavaScript (using the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/2948765)):

```
$(function() {
  // Get the cmd query parameter
  var cmd = getParameterByName('cmd');
  if(cmd) {
    // Disable the link
    $('a.cmd-' + cmd).click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
    })
    // Add a class to allow styling
    .addClass('disabled');
  }
});
```

Comment: when i used your code it gives error ReferenceError: getParameterByName is not defined

Comment: @Arif I wrote "using the code from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript/901144#901144)". So you should include the function declared in the referenced answer.

Comment: i used your function but link not disabled

Comment: how i disable link when it is clicked

Comment: @Arif `event.preventDefault();` should have disabled the link. What does `getParameterByName('cmd')` return? You could also use CSS to disable the link: `a.disabled { pointer-events: none; cursor: default; }` (based on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4416239/2948765)).

Answer (score 0):

```
.disabled {
text-decoration:none;
color:black;
 }


<a class="links" href="##"> Link1 </a></br>
<a class="links" href="##"> Link2 </a></br>
<a class="links" href="##"> link3 </a></br>


$(function(){
   $(".links").click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("disabled")){
         return false;
    }
    else{
        $(".links").removeClass("disabled");
        $(this).addClass("disabled");
    }
});
})
```

I think It will work